# jqGrid editRow posting to the server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JqGrid to display some data, and want to enable editing for one column (InvoiceStatus).

The issue is, it does not call the editurl server.php.

Thanks.

```
var lastSel;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// Generates the Category Grid, and observes for events, and acts on them   
jQuery("#list987").jqGrid({
    url:'php/selectInvoices.php?nd='+new Date().getTime(),
    datatype: "json",
    type: "POST",
    colNames:['InvoicePdfID', 'InvoiceNumber', 'TransactionID', 'InvoiceDate', 'InvoiceStatus', 'QBNumber'],
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'InvoicePdfID', index:'InvoicePdfID', width:15, hidden:true},
        {name:'InvoiceNumber', index:'InvoiceNumber', width:150},
        {name:'TransactionID', index:'TransactionID', width:150, hidden:false},
        {name:'InvoiceDate', index:'InvoiceDate', width:150},           
        {name:'InvoiceStatus', index:'InvoiceStatus', width:150, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Sent:Sent; Paied:Paied; Created:Created"}},
    {name:'QBNumber', index:'QBNumber', width:150}      
        ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager987'),
    rowNum:10,
    imgpath: 'themes/sand/images',
    sortname: 'id',    
    sortorder: "asc",   
    scrollOffset:0,
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastSel){                 
            jQuery('#list987').restoreRow(lastSel); 
            lastSel=id; 
         }
        jQuery('#list987').editRow(id, true);
    }, 
viewrecords: true,
editurl: 'php/server.php',
mytype: "POST",   
caption: "Service Types"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the line:

```
mytype: "POST",
```

Example:

```
viewrecords: true,
editurl: 'php/server.php',  
caption: "Service Types"
});
```

I just compared to a working grid that I have and it failed when I placed that in my code.

Hope this helps!

- @nbost